# Column Header Style

Tags: wpf

Hi I have the following problem when trying to create a style and apply it to the DataGrid Header get the following error

> DependencyProperty.UnsetValue} 'is not a valid value for property' ColumnHeaderStyle '. "

He failed to see that this is so, if anyone can give me an idea I would appreciate leave the grid code and style. -

```
  <!-- ************** DATAGRID ************ -->
<Style x:Key="DataGridFloatingWindow" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#fcfcfc" />
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Horizontal" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <!--<Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush"/>-->
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderFloatingWindow}" >

        <!--<Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="3,0" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#dedede"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#dedede"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Transparent"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>-->
    </Setter>



    <Setter Property="RowStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#dcdcdc" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.50"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#787676"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6e6e6e"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>


    <Setter Property="CellStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource KozukaGothicPro}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6e6e6e" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 5 10 7" />

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#dcdcdc" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#040404"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style x:Key="DataGridHeaderFloatingWindow" 
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="28" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Path x:Name="SortArrow" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1 z" Stretch="Fill" 
                          Grid.Column="1" Width="8" Height="6" Fill="Red" Margin="0,0,8,0" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.4" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

 <DataGrid x:Name="GeographicZones" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridFloatingWindow}" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxSelectAll"></CheckBox>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Reference CheckBoxSelectAll}, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"></CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource GridEditButtonStyle}" Content="{StaticResource GridEditDetailNormal}"></Button>
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource GridViewButtonStyle}" Content="{StaticResource GridViewDetailNormal}"></Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource FW_General_Name}" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource FW_General_Code}" Binding="{Binding Path=Code}" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{DynamicResource FW_General_Enabled}">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource GridViewEnabled}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridIconOnEnabled}" />
                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource GridViewDisabled}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridIconOnDisabled}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Is this Silverlight or WPF ? Please add the right Tag to your question.

Comment: This may seem silly, but make sure that resources that reference other resources are declared later in the file.  That is, if one resource (your DataGrid style) consumes another resource (your header style), make sure you declare the header style first in the XAML file.

Comment: Thanks you were right, move the declaration of Style Header already been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `StaticResource` in this line with `DynamicResource` -

```
<Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle"
        Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderFloatingWindow}" >
```

to

```
<Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle"
        Value="{DynamicResource DataGridHeaderFloatingWindow}" >
```

Or,move the style `DataGridHeaderFloatingWindow` above `DataGridFloatingWindow` in your xaml so as to resolve the reference.

With `DynamicResource` the reference will be resolved at runtime when the dataGrid will be loaded. Whereas, for `StaticResource` reference need to be resolved at loading of xaml, so any `StaticResource used in the xaml should be defined above its usage`.

Comment: Thanks you were right, move the declaration of Style Header already been solved, it also proves the DynamicResource it seems better to declare the styles without having to respect an order